# How to import data into MySQL from CSV file separated with comma (,)?

Tags: mysql, csv

I've nearly 5MB of data separated with comma (,) and I want to import it into MySQL using PHPMyAdmin which already have in-built function to import data from CSV.

The table structure is something like this

```
+------+----------------------+-----------+
| myid | field1               | field2    |
+------+----------------------+-----------+
|    1 |                      |           |
|    2 |                      |           |
|    3 |                      |           |
+------+----------------------+-----------+
```

I want the data to be inserted into field1 only and I tried to import it but it is giving error unable to import (format error). Even I tried to import the data by creating a temp. table with single row but still unable to do.

The format of the CSV file is
192.168.1.1,127.1.1.1,127.0.0.1..... 
I've downloaded the file from http://www.stopforumspam.com/downloads/

Please help
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the structure of your csv?

Comment: The table has to match csv structure,import it as is and then from the table created move it in in your table with GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: I've downloaded the data from http://www.stopforumspam.com/downloads/